# I cannot drag a user control which i have duplicated in a panel

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop, user-controls, panel

I have a user control on my form which i can drag and drop. I have also added a panel on the form (the usercontrol is NOT on the panel). When I double click on the usercontrol, I can duplicate the user control on the panel but I cannot find a way to move(drag and drop) the user control which I have created on the panel. Below are the codes I have worked so far. Could anyone please help me.

```
Private dragging As Boolean
   Private beginX, beginY As Integer

   Dim usercontrol As New UCtest

   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       For Each cntrl As Control In Me.Controls
           If TypeOf (cntrl) Is UCtest Then
               AddHandler cntrl.MouseDown, AddressOf Control_MouseDown
               AddHandler cntrl.MouseMove, AddressOf Control_MouseMove
               AddHandler cntrl.MouseUp, AddressOf Control_MouseUp
           End If
       Next
   End Sub

   Private Sub Control_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
       Dim cntrl As Control = CType(sender, Control)
       dragging = True
       beginX = e.X
       beginY = e.Y

   End Sub

   Private Sub Control_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
       Dim cntrl As Control = CType(sender, Control)
       If TypeOf (cntrl) Is UCtest Then
           If dragging = True Then
               cntrl.Location = New Point(cntrl.Location.X + e.X - beginX, cntrl.Location.Y + e.Y - beginY)
               Me.Refresh()
           End If
       End If

   End Sub

   Private Sub UCtest1_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles UCtest1.MouseDoubleClick
       Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(usercontrol)
   End Sub

   Private Sub Control_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
       dragging = False
   End Sub
```

Comment: You added the event handlers to the Form. You should override the corresponding methods (`OnMouseDown`, `MouseMove`) in the UserControl class you have created, not subscribe to these events in another class.

Comment: @Paul  I have tried to override the methods in the UserControl class but it is not working and I cannot even move the usercontrol which is outside the panel.